# Finding an angle in a circle with triangles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

good day! Excuse me, I am new to finding angles using a circle, and I don't know how to find X using trigonometric functions and everything else about triangle angles. What is the 100° talking about? Or, how can one proof that BE is parallel to AC? (Maybe it isn't!) What I know is the angle of ACD is going to be 78. Any help, guidance, approach would be warmly welcomed.

[image]

Comment: Is $FC$ tangent to the circle at $C$?

Comment: Oooh, yes, I think so! Thank you, that's a very good piece of information :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $100º$ refers to $\angle BOA$. Whenever you see an angle on the arc of a circle, this means that the two points are separated by that angle: in this case, $A$ and $B$ are separated by an angle of $100º$.

If $\angle BFC + \angle ACF = 180º$, then $BF$ is parallel to $AC$ (these would be co-interior angles, if you're curious). Therefore, we have to find $\angle BFC$ and $\angle ACF$ somehow.

It is often helpful to draw an extra line or two: for this problem, connect $B$ and $C$ together. Now, can you find:

- $\angle DCA$?
- $\angle BCA$ using the inscribed angle theorem (with angles $2 \theta$ and $\theta$)?
- $\angle BCF$ using the alternate angle theorem for circles?
- $\angle CEB$ using the sum of opposite angles in a cyclic quadrilateral?

and these facts will lead you to find the two angles mentioned above, and hence whether $BF$ is parallel to $AC$.

Comment: Thank you, @Toby Mak! That's a lot of guidance! Right now, I might struggle with finding those angels, but I will give a big try and research more about those theorems! :) (And that is really a lot of guidance to be able to solve similar problems to this one!)

Comment: Ah! I see! I see it a bit clearer now with the edit you made. Finding first ∠DCA, and then ∠BCA with what you told me about the 100° (I think, I think! I shall try!)

Comment: No problem at all! Thank you for putting in some time into this problem for yourself, and I believe you will learn a lot if you try.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Work with multiple isosceles triangles with one of the vertices being at the center of the circle. Start with $\triangle AOB$ and we know $\angle AOB = 100^0$, can you find $\angle OAB$? Then can you go on to find $\angle OCA$ and $\angle OCE$?

Now using the fact that $FC$ is tangent to the circle, you should be able to find $\angle FCE$.

Then can you find $\angle FEC$ given $ABEC$ is a cyclic quadrilateral?

Now you know two angles of $\triangle FCE$. So you know $\angle X$.

Comment: Woow, thank you so much!!! I plan on trying to solve this on today's evening. I really like the ideas and ways of solving this. You are right about the isosceles triangles :) So far I think I can get to the point of FC. After that, I hope I can go through! But I will indeed learn a lot to be able to solve other similar problems :) Thank you!